# How do i use ngStyle with Interpolation

Tags: angular, typescript

So in my app, there are 2 slidebars which output a value between 1 and 100. based on the output, i want to set the margin of a div to whatever the output is in percentage. Ive tried many things and google didnt seem to have an answer to my exact problem

So in the .ts file i have a variable called "xpos" which stores the output of the slider. The following code is my attempt on solving my problem but it doesnt seem to work;

```html
<p [ngStyle]="{margin-left.%: {{xpos}}}">Test</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': xpos+'%'}"> Test </p>
```

If your using the square brackets on an attribute you do not have to wrap your variables in curly braces.

Comment: Thanks, im still learning angular so i really appreciate tips :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a single property, in this case `margin-left`, you can also use `[style]`:

```
<p [style.margin-left.%]="xpos">Test</p>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjbmfh) in action. That being said @NorbertBartko has a correct answer. It can also be written as:

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'margin-left.%': xpos}"> Test </p>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks, i only added one property for simplicity reasons ^^ You really helped me :D